# How do you write CSV files to a specific folder that you've recently created in python?

Tags: python, csv, directory

This is what I currently have:

```
CSVdir = "./CSV_folder"
realCSVdir = os.path.realpath(CSVdir)
if not os.path.exists(CSVdir):
    os.makedirs(CSVdir)
writer = csv.writer(open(realCSVdir + 'Movie-%s.csv' % var, 'wb'))
```

I'm trying to write my CSV files in the `CSVdir` that was just created, but it's not working.

Comment: What is failing in this? Do you have the traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've left out the path separator between `realCSVdir` and the filename.

Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for a cross-platform solution:

```
# this is meant to follow on from the `os.makedirs` line...
foupath = os.path.join(realCSVdir, 'Movie-%s.csv' % var)
fou = open(foupath, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(fou)
```